# How to use styled-components theme in Gatsby 2.0

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, gatsby

so as the title says I'm curious what is the best practise of adding a styled-components theme to Gatsby website? I've been searching through the internet without finding a definite answer but from what I've gathered I probably should do it by creating a layout in `src/layouts/index.tsx` that wraps all the pages with the ThemeProvider:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

import { defaultTheme } from '../theme/defaultTheme'

export const DefaultLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
    { children }
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

And then I'm able to use theme freely in my styled components? Which doesn't work and I'm getting a bit frustrated with this.

Comment: How did you try to access the theme in your child components?

Comment: @phpcoderx just the umm normal way I suppose but yeah I figured it out. I'll answer my own question so maybe somebody else will find this useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok well the solution was simple. Since I was following the old examples done with v1 I guess I should have known that the layouts are **not** automatically added in v2. Sigh so that layout works but I just have to add it manually:

```
import { DefaultLayout } from '../layouts/DefaultLayout'
```

...

```
  <DefaultLayout>
    <div>
      <h1>Front page</h1>
      <Button>I am a button</Button>
    </div>
  </DefaultLayout>
```

Hmmph frustrating bug but maybe that was on me.